# how to collect and write logs to file in batches after time interval using log4j2 or logback in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2, spring-logback

I am trying to make a custom log appender using log4j2. My problem is I don't want to write log immediately to a file appender but after. So, ideally, my spring boot app should collect all the logs in some data structure and then trigger writing to file after the delay of 3 minutes in batches. (I should not use spring batch since it is not a batch application but a simple spring boot starter)

Answer (score 1):

When I was writing my custom provider for Logback (as a part of [Loki4j](https://github.com/loki4j/loki-logback-appender) project) I came up with a concise implementation of a thread-safe [buffer](https://gist.github.com/nehaev/83a5332d429e3f390f0fba740157509a) that can trigger output operation by either batch size or timeout since last output.

Usage pattern:

```java
private static final LogRecord[] ZERO_EVENTS = new LogRecord[0];
private ConcurrentBatchBuffer<ILoggingEvent, LogRecord> buffer = new ConcurrentBatchBuffer<>(batchSize, LogRecord::create, (e, fl) -> eventFileLine(e, fl));


// somewhere in code where new log event arrives
var batch = buffer.add(event, ZERO_EVENTS);
if (batch.length > 0)
    handleBatch(batch);


// somewhere in scheduled method that triggers every timeoutMs
var batch = buffer.drain(timeoutMs, ZERO_EVENTS);
if (batch.length > 0)
    return handleBatch(batch).thenApply(r -> null);

// handling batches here
private void handleBatch(LogRecord[] lines) {
    // flush to file
}
```

Comment: Do you have the implementation in log4j2?

Comment: Not yet, but I have plans to port Loki appender to log4j if there's a demand for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at appenders that come with log4j2. Most of them implement functionality similar to what you describe. E.g. `RandomAccessFileAppender` will write to file only after it receives complete batch of log events from async appenders infrastructure. They all share `OutputStreamManager` or `FileManager` that encapsulates this logic:

```java
protected synchronized void write(final byte[] bytes, final int offset, final int length, final boolean immediateFlush) {
        if (immediateFlush && byteBuffer.position() == 0) {
...
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no time baed solution for this.

I have written [log4j2 appender for Loki](https://github.com/tkowalcz/tjahzi) and it has its own ring buffer and a thread that will send a batch when there is enough data or user specified timeout passed, [here](https://github.com/tkowalcz/tjahzi/blob/master/core/src/main/java/pl/tkowalcz/tjahzi/LogBufferAgent.java):

```java
 if (exceededBatchSizeThreshold() || exceededWaitTimeThreshold(currentTimeMillis)) {
            try {
                httpClient.log(outputBuffer);
            } finally {
                outputBuffer.clear();
                timeoutDeadline = currentTimeMillis + batchWaitMillis;
            }
        }
```